# How can I connect my Lenovo s850 with Ubuntu 14.4?

Tags: lenovo

I just bought Lenovo S850 smartphone and it contains only the executable file for windows OS in order to connect the phone with the computer. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: To connect it in what sense? USB, bluetooth, did you already try to connect it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to connect the phone to your computer to browse its contents. Typically the file system will be mounted just by connecting the phone to the PC using a cable provided with your charger. For both Windows and Ubuntu no executable is needed to do this as all android devices that I know of are plug in and play, if not the Drivers are automatically installed upon connecting, Perhaps the executable is some sort of useless bloatware that Lenovo wants you to install?

Another possible reason you device may not be accessible is that MTP is disabled in your settings. To resolve this, go to your Settings > Storage and in the upper right corner there should be three small dots, tap these. They will bring up "USB computer connection". Press it and make sure the box next to Media device (MTP) is checked.